# Certificate error Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have a question regarding Azure Application Gateway.

I currently have my app gateway set up. It has two backend pools, both for a different vm with a different hostname. The error I'm getting now in my Backend Health is this:

"The root certificate of the server certificate used by the backend does not match the trusted root certificate added to the application gateway. Ensure that you add the correct root certificate to whitelist the backend."

Now I've added the certificate I have from one of the vm's to the app gateway, but still I'm getting above error for both backend pools.

Does anyone know what this error exactly entails?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

This means API gateway cannot do TLS whitelist with the backend.

You will need to get the public part of root certificate used in backend server, and add it to the HTTP Setting that is associated with the backend pool.

You can add more than one certificate to cover all servers in the pool